# is there any way to change permission for push notifications on ios at runtime?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application created in ionic that uses firebase push notification.
If a user installs the application is asked if he allows the permission to send push notifications, from that moment on firebase remains the status of the permission until the user uninstalls the app.
Is there any way to change the runtime permission?
the use case is: I install the app and don't give permission for push notifications, I use it, I realize I want notifications, now how do I change the permission?

Answer (score 1):

You change it in 'Settings > TheApp > Notifications'.

Answer (score 1):

Once the user declined the permission for push notifications, it can only be changed by opening `Settings > Your App > Notifications` which means that the user will need to do that manually.

But there're some Cordova plugins that could help you with that. For example the **[Diagnostic plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin)** has a method called **[`switchToSettings`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#switchtosettings)** that:

> Opens settings page for this app.
>
> On Android, this opens the "App Info" page in the Settings app.
>
> On iOS, this opens the app settings page in the Settings app.

So you can use that plugin to open the settings page automatically so that the user could enable the notifications:

```
this.firebasePlugin.grantPermission().then((hasPermission) => {
  if(!hasPermission) {
    // Show some message to the user telling that 
    // your app will open the settings and then...
    this.diagnosticPlugin.switchToSettings();
  }
});
```

Comment: yours is a great answer for "what can the app do if the user previously denied access. But the OP posed the question as "how do I [the user] change the permission?"

Comment: That's a good point :)... But since the user mentioned that he created an app with Ionic I assumed he was interested in knowing how to allow users from that app to change the permissions.

Comment: firebasePlugin.hasPermission read from the device settings or from the fcm server?

Comment: @EmanueleGaleotti I updated the answer to use the `grantPermission` method instead but both of them work in a similar way: the result is `true/false` based on if the current device where the app is being used has granted permissions to your app or not.